# rails convert string to number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering what is a convenient function in Rails to convert a string with a negative sign into a number. e.g. `-1005.32`

When I use the `.to_f` method, the number becomes `1005` with the negative sign and decimal part being ignored.

Comment: Are you storing the result in an int rather than a float?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`.to_f` is the right way.

Example:

```
irb(main):001:0> "-10".to_f
=> -10.0
irb(main):002:0> "-10.33".to_f
=> -10.33
```

Maybe your string does not include a regular "-" (dash)? Or is there a space between the dash and the first numeral?

Added:

If you *know* that your input string is a string version of a floating number, eg, "10.2", then .to_f is the best/simplest way to do the conversion.

If you're not sure of the string's content, then using `.to_f` will give 0 in the case where you don't have any numbers in the string. It will give various other values depending on your input string too. Eg

```
irb(main):001:0> "".to_f 
=> 0.0
irb(main):002:0> "hi!".to_f
=> 0.0
irb(main):003:0> "4 you!".to_f
=> 4.0
```

The above `.to_f` behavior may be just what you want, it depends on your problem case.

Depending on what you want to do in various error cases, you can use `Kernel::Float` as Mark Rushakoff suggests, since it raises an error when it is not perfectly happy with converting the input string.

Comment: Look at the other answer, `"abcd".to_f === 0` unfortunately

Comment: `" '11.0' "` with this can we change to `11.0` using `to_f`

Answer (score 27):

You should be using [`Kernel::Float`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005965) to convert the number; on invalid input, this will raise an error instead of just "trying" to convert it.

```
>> "10.5".to_f
=> 10.5
>> "asdf".to_f # do you *really* want a zero for this?
=> 0.0
>> Float("asdf")
ArgumentError: invalid value for Float(): "asdf"
    from (irb):11:in `Float'
    from (irb):11
>> Float("10.5")
=> 10.5
```

Comment: One of the nice things about `Float()` as opposed to `Integer` is that the former doesn't convert `010` to `8` (Integer regards something starting with `0` as octal)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Or you could just pass the correct base in as the second argument: `Integer("010", 10) #=> 10` (See [`Kernel#integer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer))