# Subtracting variables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to see if a point is within a circle.I am using the Pythagorean Theorem to check, but when I use this I get `undefined method`-' for "37.33259551999998":String`. How do I subtract these variables?

```
 def getalerts
            alerts = Alert.all
            school = School.find_by_school_name(params[:school])
            latitude = params[:latitude]
            longitude = params[:longitude]
            radius = school.radius
            alertArray = Array.new()

            alerts.each do |alert|
              d = Math.sqrt(((alert.latitude - school.latitude)**2) + (alert.longitude - school.longitude)**2)

              if d < radius
                alertArray["latlng"] = alert.latitude, alert.longitude 
              end
            end
            respond_to do |format|
              format.json { render json: alertArray}      
            end
    end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails convert string to number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778093/rails-convert-string-to-number)

Comment: If you want the great-circle distance between two points given by their longitudes and latitudes, you'll want to use the [Haversine_Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Comment: @BradWerth, this question is about determining the distance between points given by the longitude and latitude. The OP has not asked how to convert a string to a number.  The OP may be attempting to difference strings, but that is not a duplicate question issue.  What is your reasoning that this is a duplicate of the answer you reference?

Comment: @CarySwoveland as accurate as that may be, based on the context of the question, I think think the OP would be happy with an accuracy of about a 10 miles. :)

Comment: Let's make this question more concrete.  Central Park in New York City is at 40 deg., 47.9 min. N (lat) and at 73 deg., 58.2 min. W (long). The White House in Washington DC is at 38 deg., 55.1 min. N (lat) and 77 deg., 3.3 min. W (long).  The great-circle distance between the two points is found to be [336 kms.](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml). The question (whose answer you now know) is whether the White House is within a circle of radius 400 kms. centered on Central Park (at the Boathouse, let's say).

Comment: I've added my vote to close this question. It proposes a ridiculous formula for calculating great-circle distance (nor does it make sense if we could bore a tunnel through the earth between the two points). Points on the earth are given by angular measurements. To get distances between them you obviously must use trigonometry and (assuming the earth is a sphere) the earth's diameter. What's worse is that several readers saw the problem as only one of merely converting a string to a number!

Comment: @CarySwoveland - the op asks only "How do I subtract these variables?" Also, check  the accepted answer, it is the same answer as referenced. Sometimes, the exact question asked is really the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `to_f` on alert and school latitudes and longitudes.

Converting to float will preserve decimal point numbers (unlike `to_i`)

```
d = Math.sqrt(
  ((alert.latitude.to_f - school.latitude.to_f)**2)
  + (alert.longitude.to_f - school.longitude.to_f)**2)
```

Comment: assuming that the values latitude and longitude are truly latitude and longitude, this is just plain wrong,  you get a number,  but it is __NOT__ the distance you are looking for.

Comment: @nPn yep. I'm justing assuming OP wants to subtract strings and get rid of those erros. If accurate distance calc is needed haversine_formula will works a thousand times better (as you commented)

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it is clear that subtraction option is performed on strings and hence it is not valid. You can convert strings to integers using `to_i` method. So try this :

```
d = Math.sqrt(((alert.latitude.to_i - school.latitude.to_i)**2) + (alert.longitude.to_i - school.longitude.to_i)**2)
```

Also, if you want them converted to floating values, you will have to use `to_f` method.

Comment: Longitude and latitude are angular measurements. Are you sure you want to convert them to integers and apply the Pythagorean Theorem?

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge, but are angular measurements floating values?

Answer (score 0):

Cary makes the correct point.  Even if the initial question is about a technical problem with tying to subtract string representations of floating point numbers, the real issue is that you need to calculate the distance between two points on the earth.  Here is a ruby implementation of the haversine formula

https://github.com/kristianmandrup/haversine/blob/master/lib/haversine.rb